# Installing a Cygwin compiled Python module in my Windows installation

Tags: python, numpy, cygwin, ipython

I'm trying to compile and use the [PyGRIB](http://code.google.com/p/pygrib/) module.  There is no binary distribution of the module, so I have compiled using Cygwin.  I would really like to be able to use the module in my windows python installation -- I already have numpy, matplotlib, and a development environment setup for my windows installation.  How do I do this?

It looks like the Cygwin install creates the following two files:

```
pygrib-1.9.3-py2.6.egg-info
pygrib.dll
```

in my `c:\cygwin\lib\python2.6\site-packages` directory.

I have tried copying these to: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

If I can't do this, can I get IPython in Cygwin?  I haven't seen it in the setup utility.

Comment: It sounds like you should be compiling with the mingw compilers instead. This is how numpy and scipy are compiled, and the result is fully compatible with native binary libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the easiest way to compile on windows when using python is to just use the free visual studios distribution. I've installed many different packages that way and never had an issue. Normally, the installation will place the path variable on your path, but you will need to verify that.

You need to make sure to use 2008 though, and not 2010.

You can retrieve it from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/express/future/bb421473

Do note, if you go this way, it will mean you will have to reinstall any other compiled python binary packages (numpy, scipy, etc)

That said, I notice you are downloading a 2.6egg to a 2.7 distro. Off the top of my head, I'm not certain that 2.6 and 2.7 were compiled using the same compiler, but I believe they were. In any event, that could be your problem, either the package doesn't support 2.7, or 2.6 doesn't compile with the same compiler as 2.7.